# How to send out multi emails using mailgun API in PHP

Tags: php, email, mailgun

I have tried to run the following code for sending multiple emails using mailgun **API** in **PHP**. But no email is sent using the code. My code is :

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

$mgClient = new Mailgun("my-api-key");
$domain = "sandboxfa3e9009746840be831c6edc9e9f1ee9.mailgun.org";
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage("$domain",
array('from' => 'Mailgun Sandbox - Test  
       <postmaster@sandboxfa3e9009746840be831c6edc9e9f1ee9.mailgun.org>',
    'to' => 'email_1@gmail.com, email_2@gmail.com',
    'subject' => 'Mailgun bulk-msg test for KB',
    'text' => 'Your mail do not support HTML',
    'html' => 'html-portion here...',
    'recipient-variables' => '{"email_1@gmail.com": {"first":"Name-1", 
     "id":1}, "email_2@gmail.com": {"first":"Name-2", "id": 2}}')
 );
 var_dump($result);
 ?>
 #===============================================
```

Have i do any mistake in the code to send multi email ? If you have any solution, please help.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be sharing your API key. I suggest removing it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I found this from their API. (Not as answer maybe. Just a reference)

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

$mg = Mailgun::create('key-example');

# $mg->messages()->send($domain, $params);
$mg->messages()->send('example.com', [
  'from'    => 'bob@example.com',
  'to'      => 'sally@example.com',
  'subject' => 'The PHP SDK is awesome!',
  'text'    => 'It is so simple to send a message.'
]);
```

[Source](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php)

Answer (score -1):

Aside from what Abdulla pointed out I see that you're writing `"$domain"` as the literal domain parameter. If you write it with quotation-marks, then it will be interpreted as a string, and not the variable itself.

Change the following and it should work:

```
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage("$domain",
[...]
```

to

```
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain,
[...]
```

Comment: in php both should work. Variables (strings starting with the dollar sign) are parsed inside double quotes. They' re not parsed in single quotes.